# Meaning of expression "They are calling for rain"

Tags: usage, phrase-meaning, expressions

Whenever the radio/TV weather forecasters predict any kind of rainy weather,
you hear people, when chatting or making small talk with friends and/or family:
"They are calling for rain."
Is this expression used correctly in that context?

Answer (score 3):

"They're calling for rain" means *In the professional judgment of some meteorologists, rain is to be expected.* "They" when used like that, with no obvious referent, refers to an anonymous authority of some kind.